# My Preference Activity is completely black

Tags: java, android, preferenceactivity, preference

I'm trying to do a settings screen with preferenceActivity but it doesnt work, when I click Settings on my menu it gives me black preference Screen :/

[PreferenceActivity ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F8gXs.jpg)

preferences_activity.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">

 <PreferenceCategory
     android:title="Zamanlayıcı"
     android:key="Countdowntimer_key">

     <CheckBoxPreference
         android:key="countdowntimer_loop_pKey"
         android:summary="Süre bittikten sonra yeniden otomatik başlat"
         android:title="Zamanlayıcı Döngüsü"
         android:defaultValue="false"
         />

 </PreferenceCategory>




</PreferenceScreen>
```

PreferenceActivity.Java

```
   public class PreferenceActivity extends android.preference.PreferenceActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setTheme(R.style.ZaaTheme);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences_activity);


    }
}
```

Comment: your theme is doing that. Try setting a clear theme for that activity or instead just create a custom xml for your preference activity that just needs a listview

Comment: I already tried to set the theme to another but it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem in certain devices. Setting theme in manifest helped for me, e.g.
   `android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.DayNight"`